# PHP http_get vs fsockopen to HTTPS server?

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, https, pecl

In PHP, what are the biggest considerations when choosing between using **http_get**("https://...") and a sockets loop with **fsockopen**("ssl://..."), **fputs**() and **fread**()?

I’ve seen a couple of implementations lately that use the latter. Is that just old legacy code or is there some good reason for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http_get` requires a PECL extension, which is not bundled with PHP.

`fsockopen` is more complicated to use (requires looping, sending the headers manually, reading the headers manually, and, in general, more code), but is part of the PHP (it's always present).

In my opinion, the best fail-safe option is to use the http wrapper, as in:

```
file_get_contents('https://...')
```

The http wrapper, however, has its own set of limitations – no digest authentication, no automatic handling of encoded content, etc. So if either the [PECL http extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) or the [curl extension](http://php.net/curl) are available, those would probably be a better option.

Comment: Thanks. For some odd reason, the host I'm accessing has problems with the fsockopen() approach and file_get_contents() will work fine for my current application. (Actually, I'll probably use simplexml_load_file().)